# Are these formulations of lagrange multiplier theorem equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Our professor stated and proved the following theorem (my translation):

> Let $m < n$ and $D$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $G: D \to
>  \mathbb{R}^m$, $G = (g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_m)$ be a $C^1$ map on $D$ of
> maximal rank ($\text{rank}(G) = m$). Let $M = G^{-1}(\{0\}) \neq
>  \emptyset$. Let $f \in C^1(D)$. Suppose $f$ has a local extrema at $p
>  \in M$ as a function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$. Then, there exist
> constants $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m \in \mathbb{R}$, such that
> $(Df)(p) = \sum_1^m {\lambda_j(Dg_j)(p)}$.

The book we're using states and proves the following theorem (also my translation):

> Let function $f \in C^1$, $f(x) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, at point $a$, local extrema under additional conditions:
> $$ g_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0$$
> $$ g_2(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0 $$
> $$ \cdots $$
> $$ g_m(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0 $$
> where $g_i$ for $i \in \{ 1, 2, \ldots, m \}$ are $C^1$ functions around $a$ (and of course $g_1(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = g_2(a_1, \ldots, a_n)
>  = \ldots = g_m(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = 0)$. Let the gradients $$(\text{grad}(g_1))(a), (\text{grad}(g_2))(a), \ldots,
>  (\text{grad}(g_m))(a)$$ be linearly independent. Then there exist
> real numbers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_m$, such that $a$
> is a stationaty point of function $$F = f - \lambda_1 g_1 - \lambda_2 g_2 -
>  \ldots - \lambda_m g_m$$

Both theorems look very similar or at least related to me. This makes me wonder if they are completely equivalent and how could one show that they are. How are the hypothesis in both theorems equivalent?

Comment: Both theorems are equivalent: The functions $g_1, g_2, \dots, g_m$ in the second version are the components of $G:D \to \mathbb R^m$ in the first version. The fact that $g_1(a)=\dots = g_m(a)=0$ corresponds to restricting $F$ (in the first version) to $M= G^{-1}(\{0\}$. In the second version the stationary point of $F$ means that $DF=0$ which is equivalent to the condition for the derivatives in the first version. The only thing I honestly don't know is why the condition on linear independence of the gradients is there in the second version...

Comment: @Lukas I think the condition for linear independence of gradients is related to the condition that G is of maximal rank, but I don't see how

Comment: Yes, you are right - in the first version we have that $DG$ has full rank so the rows of the matrix are linearly independent - which is exactly equivalent to the gradients being linearly independent.

Comment: @Lukas ok, great, thank you